# What is .vec file in a .s, .c, and .h context? Specifically, stm32f10x_md.vec

Tags: c, assembly, vector, arm, stm32

What is a .vec file in a .s, .c, and .h context? Specifically, stm32f10x_md.vec. I keep getting stuck on "ISR_HANDLER USART3_IRQHandler" inside the .vec file and all googling leads me to reading about openCV. The .vec file doesn't seem to exist anywhere. The closest thing seems to be startup_stm32f10x_md.s. I'm using Rowley CrossWorks with the Nucleo f103rb.

These are the file's entire contents. Based on the answers so far I wonder if .vec is specific to CrossWorks?

```
ISR_HANDLER WWDG_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER PVD_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TAMPER_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER RTC_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER FLASH_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER RCC_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER EXTI0_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER EXTI1_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER EXTI2_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER EXTI3_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER EXTI4_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER DMA1_Channel4_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER ADC1_2_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER USB_HP_CAN1_TX_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER USB_LP_CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER EXTI9_5_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TIM1_BRK_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TIM1_UP_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TIM1_TRG_COM_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TIM2_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TIM3_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER TIM4_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER I2C1_EV_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER I2C1_ER_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER I2C2_EV_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER I2C2_ER_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER SPI1_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER SPI2_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER USART1_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER USART2_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER USART3_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER EXTI15_10_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER RTCAlarm_IRQHandler
ISR_HANDLER USBWakeUp_IRQHandler
```

Comment: I believe it is the interrupt vector table

Comment: That is not specific to CrossWorks, all STM32-based projects (and basically all projects for microcontrollers supporting interrupts) have a table (either in C or assembly) that associate an interrupt event with a function (this is called an interrupt vector table or IVT). Every time the interrupt line is triggered with an event (and that interrupt is not masked), the corresponding function is called. Example, when the DMA1_Channel1 interrupt is triggered, the DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler function is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a file that contains a portion of an interrupt vector table. Consider a startup assembly file that looks like:

```
_vectors:
  .word __stack_end__
  ...
  ISR_HANDLER SysTick_Handler 
  #if defined(__TARGET_LD)
    #include "STM32F10X_LD.vec"
  #elif defined(__TARGET_MD)
    #include "STM32F10X_MD.vec"
  ...
  #endif
```

Using separate .vec files you can use the same top level Startup.s file independently on the target microcontroller you're using and just customize/include your target specific .vec file

Answer (score 1):

It's an ordinary assembly file that's meant to be included in another assembly file.  The name `ISR_HANDLER` is an assembly macro defined in some other file, maybe `startup_stm32f10x_md.s`, and would look something like this (taken from [Rowley Associates's `STM32_Startup.s`](https://github.com/limhyon/esc32/blob/master/src/STM32_Startup.s)):

```
.macro ISR_HANDLER name= 
   .section .vectors, "ax" 
   .word \name 
   .section .init, "ax" 
   .thumb_func 
   .weak \name 
 \name: 
 1: b 1b /* endless loop */ 
 .endm
```

This macro puts an entry in the interrupt vector table for the named interrupt routine, and it also provides a default implementation of the routine, an infinite loop, in case the application doesn't provide one of its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the .vec is a section you may find it in the linker script. Like MPC56XX there is a section called .vect especially for interrupt vector table.

This is my first time to hear about .vec file.

This is a great chance to follow this question to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

the cortex-m's are nice in that you dont HAVE to wrap exceptions with special entry or return stuff.  So other than reset dealing with .data and .bss you can get away with no assembly for bootstrap, but you still have to generate the vector table somehow and populate it with addresses to functions.  So this looks like one way to do it.  I suspect it is specific to that toolchain.  The easy way of course is to just use the assembler and assembler directives since you have the assembler there already to support the compiler.